# C# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The caller does not have permission

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I've created an API key for my application, and have passed it in as-per the example listed here (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#simple). I'm getting the **Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The caller does not have permission**. What might I be missing?

Source code

```
var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    ApplicationName = "Application",
    ApiKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleSheetsAPIKey"]
});

// Define request parameters.
string spreadsheetId = "[omitted]";
string range = "Sheet1";
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

ValueRange response = request.Execute();
IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values; // bombs here
if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
    foreach (var row in values)
    {
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[4]);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
 }
```

My api key is created and has "no restrictions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that this spreadsheet was under my google account. By making my google spreadsheet public `share` > `advanced` > `public on the web`, the above code works. (and since this is not sensitive data, I'm fine making this spreadsheet public

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by deleting the file "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user" - generated in method GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...)